# pd.read_html-ValueError: No tables found

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am just trying to load the csv file through html but I am getting below error

my code:

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv")

df.head()

Error showing:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2 import pandas as pd
3 url = "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv"

4 df = pd.read_html("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv")

5 df.head()
....
....
ValueError: No tables found

ValueError: No tables found
This is my first stackoverflow question, so if I am not able to convey the message than please let me know and any help will be appreciated, Thank You

Comment: Use `pd.read_csv()`. `pd.read_table()` is for processing data from `<table>` tags within an HTML document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) is for processing HTML documents, reading data contained within the `<table>` tag inside the HTML document to be processed.

To process CSV files, you need [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

This will accept a URL as an argument, so the following should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hadley/data-baby-names/master/baby-names.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.head()
```

Comment: Yaa Mark yesterday I did the same and it worked but again I applied similiar method to process excel file which is in .xls format. But I got byte error. here below I have pasted the code.                               import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("https://github.com/jbwhit/coal-exploration/blob/master/data/coalpublic2013.xls")
df.head()                                                                                          Error: XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!'

Comment: [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) you need to make sure you have the relevant Excel module installed: `pip3 install openpyxl xlrd` I recommend to you Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney